# How do I know what progress will be lost by changing my quest?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am currently stuck in Act II Inferno and sometimes I try to get further in the story. Recently I killed Zoltun Kulle and talked to everybody quest related afterwards.

Then a friend asked me if I could help him in Act I, so I switched my quest.

When I came back to my game, the last available quest was "The Soulstone Chamber", so I had to kill Kulle again.

Now I am at the last quest for Act II where I have to kill the lord of lies. I am stuck and want to farm for better equipment, but I do not want to do everything all over again.

So basically what I am asking is:

When will quests be really finished, so that I can switch quests and never do the last one again?

Comment: this just happened to me ON ACT 2 as well which im SUPER pissed!

Comment: Here is an even stranger thing: I killed Belial, got into Act 3, could not finish the first quest (4 light fires) as I was totally broke and I could not get into Act 3 again. Some time later a friend invited me to kill Azmodan (he was good enough to carry). Now I have Act 3 unlocked and can access the first and the last few quests. VEEEERY strange.

Comment: All these comments, while helpful, are starting to scare me lol....this latest save loss kinda turned me off and now im starting to turn down friends for co-op games for fear of loosing more savegame progress. Sucks too because im LOVING this game thusfar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you leave a game and rejoin without changing quest, you will resume at your last "Checkpoint". If you change quest however, you will resume your quest at the last started quest, not at the last checkpoint (of the quest in progress). If you killed Kulle, and didn't deliver all the quests, when you then changed and rejoined you'd have to do Kulle over again, you'd start on the last quest step before killing him.

I think there probably was one more NPC to talk to in your case, so that the quest didn't "complete" but just got "updated".

For example, if you start on Lord of Lies and fail on Belial, and leave game. If you then resume, you should be starting just outside the throne, and not have to kill the nasties up the stairs first. If you changed quest and then resumed on this one, you'd start out in the city and have to fight up again.

Hope this cleared something for you :)

> **PS**: Using the checkpoint reached is useful for farming, for example
> Sarkoth in act1 is easily farmed if you do the quest to kill the
> wretched mothers, then leave and resume just after the checkpoint on
> the north side of old ruins. You then leave, resume and backtrack past
> 2-4 mobs (one group), and check for the door being open.
>
> **Update** As of patch 1.0.7 - When resuming a game, players will now be placed in town instead of at the last known checkpoint (a portal will be available to take you to your last known checkpoint, if desired)