# Diablo 3 coop overwrote single player game to older save

Tags: diablo-iii

So long story short, I was near the last episodes(?) of ACT 2 when a friend invited me to a coop game. When I was done, I quit, went to the menu and hit resume and when I go in, it started me ALL the way back in ACT2 episode/chapter 1 when you first get to the city.

I go ahead and manually start the last episode I was on in act 2 but it literally took away all my last items, maps(uncovered/traveled to), equipped items etc..

I still have all my powers and slots that I set them to but essentially I'm going to have to redo all of the last missions I did before I joined that game.

My question is, is this a bug? Or something deliberate (which I highly doubt).
It upsets me because now I'm paranoid I'll lose data when I join someone else's missions.

Any one experience this or something I did wrong? I mean I always quit the same way so not sure whats going on.

Answer (score 7):

If you go to "Change quest" on the main menu, you can change it to the quest you had been on when you left.  You may lose a small amount of progress, but it isn't much.

See this [related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73823/how-do-i-know-what-progress-will-be-lost-by-changing-my-quest) for more information

Comment: wao really...thats just....just horrible, Kind of saving system is this?!....i just lost ALL of ACT 2 #7Blood and sand...it essentially restarted itself.

Comment: F*%* so now i have to do this all over again...great....Thanks for the Reply and link @ Dave

Comment: @somdow Glad I could help - the save system is a bit silly, sorry you lost progress :/

Comment: @DaveMcClelland You are at 7777 right now o.O !

Comment: @Foxtrot I saw that too.  While it's a neat number, I won't be too sad to see an upvote change it :)

Comment: @DaveMcClelland lol I want to up vote your good answer, but I also enjoy that number... damn +1 :P