# How would switching difficulty affect my character?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I am a Lv.60+3 Demon Hunter playing through the campaign on Inferno and want to go back and play through the campaign on a lower difficulty, will I, for example, lose any stats on my character?

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no penalty for changing the difficulty.  You can go back to Act 1 Normal and your character will be exactly the same.

The downside is that the rewards are based on where you are in terms of acts and difficulty, so you will gain much less experience and find really poor items at lower difficulties/acts.

Switching quests may cause you to [lose progress in your current quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73823/how-do-i-know-what-progress-will-be-lost-by-changing-my-quest) regardless of whether or not you change the difficulty setting.

Comment: Additionally, you may lose your progress on your current quest in inferno -- when you decide to go back to inferno, you will start from the beginning of a quest.

Comment: It's worth noting that some people farm lower difficulties for experience and gold. For example, the demon hunter has a build with a focus on AoE and they just tear through nightmare act 3 with 40 gold radius pickup.

Comment: @Peter, yes, that's a problem whether you switch difficulties or just switch quests in the same difficulty.  I've made a note of it, though.

Comment: @VaelVictus, not really what the asker's asking, but that's a good comment nonetheless.